# How to say "Double negation affirms by accident"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, philosophy-terms, logic, aristotle, negation

I want to know how to say, "Double negation affirms by accident" or "Double negation affirms accidentally."  Would it be *duplex negatio affirmat per accidens*?  This is in reference to the idea from logic and grammar that double negation affirms and from the idea in metaphysics that properties either are essential or accidental.

I'm coming to this in specific reference to the following excerpt from Arist. *Int*. 14.23b15-17: “*Si ergo quod bonum et bonum et non malum est, et hoc quidem secundum se, illud vero secundum accidens (accidit enim ei malum non esse)*.”  In the 'original' Classical Attic this was: "εἰ οὖν τὸ ἀγαθὸν καὶ ἀγαθὸν καὶ οὐ κακόν ἐστιν, καὶ τὸ μὲν καθ’ αὑτὸ τὸ δὲ κατὰ συμβεβηκός (συμβέβηκε γὰρ αὐτῷ οὐ κακῷ εἶναι)."

Comment: Do you mean it in a strictly logical context? FWIW, double negation does **not** mean affirmation in every language, despite logics. E.g. in French negation is sometimes compulsorily double, and in Spanish double negation just adds emphasis. Not sure how it works in Latin, though

Comment: @Rafael: In Latin too, double negation sometimes adds emphasis (retaining the overall negation). A 'general negative' such as _non_, _numquam_, or _nihil_ isn't 'destroyed' (_Allen & Greenough_'s term) but is merely 'subdivided' (_Gildersleeve & Lodge_'s term) by succeeding negatives such as _neque_, _neque...neque_, _non solum/tantum...sed etiam_, and _ne...quidem_.

Comment: Are you sure you want to say "by accident"? I have never heard the philosophical *per accidens* translated that way, because it's highly misleading to a modern English speaker.

Comment: @brianpck I disagree. This is a part of the formal language of the discipline, which has some words that in common English are interpreted differently. A good example of this is Socrates’ _Apology_ (Apología) by Plato; here ‘apology’ clearly has a different meaning than the common meaning of a begging of pardon, or German _Bedauern_ (in this context, an apology is a defence).

Comment: @CannedMan It is much more common to translate Latin *per accidens* or Greek *κατὰ συμβεβηκός* as "accidentally," not "by accident." I'm sure you could find scattered examples of the latter, but it seems needlessly misleading.

Comment: You have a fair point, though I am not sure it is relevant in the case of discipline-specific terminology. It is, of course, highly important that when using words commonly used (with its common definition) in a discipline specific context (and its specialised definition), one is intellectually honest and declares what the meaning of the word is in its new context. Otherwise, one ends up doing as Jordan Peterson, using words such as ‘religion’ with a meaning undeclared to the audience our opponent, destroying the foundations needed for an intellectually honest discussion.

Comment: To give a well-known example from philosophy: ‘thing’. Philosophical ‘thing’ and vulgar ‘thing’ are usually not the same at all, spanning all the way from the ancient Greeks to our age’s noumenal ‘Ding an sich’.